# ScrollView for images Objective C (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a welcome page for my app (with screenshots).

I have taken some samples and made it into a text scroll. I have tried for weeks without any success. Thanks

```
int numberOfPages = 5;
UIScrollView *someScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
someScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
someScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfPages * someScrollView.frame.size.width, someScrollView.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:someScrollView];
   
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
    UILabel *tmpLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * someScrollView.frame.size.width + 20,
                                                                  20,
                                                                  someScrollView.frame.size.width - 40,
                                                                  20)];
    tmpLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    tmpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"THIS ACTUALLY WORKS!! %d", i];
    [someScrollView addSubview:tmpLabel];
}
```

Here is my failed attempt to do with images:

```
int numberOfPages = 5;
UIScrollView *someScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
someScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
someScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfPages * someScrollView.frame.size.width, someScrollView.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:someScrollView];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
    UIImageView *tmpLabel = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * someScrollView.frame.size.width + 20,
                                                                  20,
                                                                  someScrollView.frame.size.width - 40,
                                                                  20)];
    tmpLabel.imageAlignment = UIImageAlignmentCenter;
    tmpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"THIS ACTUALLY WORKS!! %d", i];
    [someScrollView addSubview:tmpLabel];
}
    UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:subview1.frame];
    
    if (i == 0) {
        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingScreen1.png"];
    }else if (i == 1){
        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingScreen2.png"];
    }else if (i == 2){
        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingScreen3.png"];
    }else {
        imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"openingScreen4.png"];
    }
```

I also might need to remove the word "Parse" unless the images above sit on top of it? I cannot locate the word.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
UIScrollView *someScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                                              self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                                              self.view.frame.size.height)];
someScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[someScrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];

//setup internal views
NSInteger numberOfPages = 5;


for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
{
     CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width+10;
    UILabel *tmpLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin,70,self.view.frame.size.width,25)];
    tmpLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    tmpLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"THIS ACTUALLY WORKS!! %d", i+1];
    [someScrollView addSubview:tmpLabel];



    // calculate the width


    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                          CGRectMake(xOrigin, tmpLabel.frame.size.height + tmpLabel.frame.origin.y + 10,
                                     self.view.frame.size.width,
                                     self.view.frame.size.height)]; // customize your width, height and y co ordinates

    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                       @"openingScreen%d.jpg", i+1]];
    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [someScrollView addSubview:image];


}
//set the scroll view content size
someScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
someScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width *
                                        numberOfPages, 
                                        self.view.frame.size.height);
//add the scrollview to this view
[self.view addSubview:someScrollView];
```

the sample OutPut is

[image]

here I attached the [sample Project](https://www.sendspace.com/file/f00fq8) also, please use this

Comment: Where do I refer to my images (.png) files?

Comment: Nope- didn't work. All I can see is the screenshot in my initial post.  I  feel like the word "Parse" is sitting on top of my images or somthing?

Comment: I was able to remove the parse Logo (set it to nil) still your code is not showing 'on top' (or anywhere). My code in my example is the only one that works- but its showing text (not images)

Comment: @Yian -- check the updated answer, in my code is works, and I attached the sample project also , if you need that use it

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code to something like

```
int numberOfPages = 5;
    UIScrollView *someScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    someScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    //set the scroll view delegate to self so that we can listen for changes
    someScrollView.delegate = self;
    someScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfPages * someScrollView.frame.size.width, someScrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:someScrollView];

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
        //set the origin of the sub view
        CGFloat myOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

        //get the sub view and set the frame
        UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, someScrollView.frame.size.height)];
       imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"openingScreen%d.png",i ]];


        //add the subview to the scroll view
         [someScrollView addSubview:imageView1];
    }
```

Add scroll view Delegate methods

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

}


//dragging ends, please switch off paging to listen for this event
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *) targetContentOffset NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0)
{

    //find the page number you are on

        CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        NSLog(@"Dragging - You are now on page %i",page);



}
```

Comment: Thank you for this- i am totally new to obj-c what do you mean add to scroll view delegate? Does that go in a different file?

Comment: just copy those methds in you view controller the code will work fine even if you don't do

Comment: Nope didn't work. The page is blank. It seems like it only worked with my text view. My .png's are in the correct location/folder

Comment: Can you make sure you images name is same as you posted in code and included in project..